# Get session cookie name

Tags: asp.net, session, sessionid, session-cookies

Is it possible to get session cookie name in medium trust level? The code below works in full trust, but throws a security exception in medium trust level.

```
string sessionCookieName = ((SessionStateSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState")).CookieName;
```

Comment: I use java applet and need to pass session name and session id to it to preserve session values when applet make request to the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **HTTP_COOKIE server variable** from the Request object, to get the cookie string that was included with the request.

```
string cookieString = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_COOKIE"]
```

If what you want is to obtain the session cookie name from the web.config, why don't you add a simple entry in the **appSettings** section containing the **session cookie name**?

```
    <appSettings>       
        <add key="SessionCookieName" value="__SessionCookieName"/>
    <appSetting>

    <sessionState cookieName="__SessionCookieName"  />
```

Then you can read the web.config setting value by using the following code:

```
public static bool SessionCookieName
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionCookieName"]; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I was hoping there are some property like we have for the SessionID - Session.SessionID, something like Session.SessionCookieName. But it seems there are no easy way to do it :(

Comment: @Andrey: also consider that for ASP.Net there are two kinds of cookies one for Authentication and another for Session. The HTTP_COOKIE server variable contains both.

Comment: For others - @ArceBrito's solution doesn't honour the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself) ... and so leaves developer teams at risk of failing to update something in both places if they're not aware of the need. IMHO always better to limit to one entry if at all possible (and not impacting performance).